# Can vim substitute a special python expression as a whole raw sentence?

Tags: python, regex, vim

I got a expression like:

```
int(i[10])
```

I want to change this as a whole into

```
int(arg_dict["count"])
```

both have lots of special characters.

Is there a way that I can ignore all its special characters in these two stuff and treat them as raw material in vim ?

for example, I want to make the following block work with your answer

```
:%s/#your answer# int(i[10])/#your answer# int(arg_dict["count"])
```

Comment: Why do you need to include the rest of the line in the regex? You can do `%s/int(i\[10\])/int(arg_dict["count"])/g` to replace just that fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "special" characters, here, are `[]` so they are the only ones you need to escape:

```
:s/int(i\[10\])/int(arg_dict["count"])/g
```

If you want to make use of capturing you will need to escape the `()` of the capture group as well:

```
:s/\(int(\)i\[10\])/\1arg_dict["count"])/g
```

Comment: why in your first line of code, I need not to escape [] in the arg_dict["count"] clause? And what's that \1 stuff in the second clause?

Comment: 1. Because you don't have to deal with "special" characters in the replacement part apart from `/` or \. 2. See `:help \1`.